# In openlayers 3, how to fill the polygon with a picture from a url?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I would like to add a picture in the polygon, however, I do not find such function in openlayers 3. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125098/how-to-draw-a-polygon-in-openlayer-3

Comment: Thanks for your link. However, it seems you did not understand my question. I do not want to draw a polygon, I want to add a picture in a existing polygon.

Comment: Do you want to add a single image inside the polygon or do you want to fill the polygon with the supplied icon????

Comment: Actually, i want to add a video from a url inside the polygon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [Pull Request #4632](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4632) you can use a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillStyle) as [`ol.style.Fill#color`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.Fill.html) property and [create a pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern).

Something like this:

```
var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://i.imgsafe.org/73d1273.png';

img.onload = function(){
  var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');

  // featurePoly is ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(...))
  featurePoly.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: pattern
    })
  }));
};
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/nt6ae1Ld/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is really close to my requirement. I would like to replace the img with a video from a url, can CanvasRenderingContext2D also achieve this?

Comment: No, no way. Only colors, gradients and pictures.

Comment: Thanks. I find the example. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974906(v=vs.85).aspx  
It shows how to use a video as fill style.

Comment: @JohnTang Oh no! Don't use this. This is IE only. Will you require IE to your clients?

Comment: No, we need to open it in all browsers. So I have to find another way. Thanks very much for your help, really appreciated it.

Comment: @JohnTang I guess your question is answered, so you could choose an answer and finish this topic.

Comment: I just tried this approach using openlayers 6, and the method produced in the answer still works as explained for images.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what would be the visual output of your requirement but I may give you the direction to solve your problem.

OL3 can use predifined styles or an array of styles or even a function that returns a style for each feature supplied. So you should propably use the style function to achieve your goal.
Lets say that you want to place one image within every vector polygon. 
Consider the following code snip

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: 'http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.0/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
  }),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
   var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#ffcc33',
        width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
      })
    })
  ];
  var mygeomType = feature.getGeometry().getType();
  //handle the case of polygons/multipolygons
  var retGeom = null;
  if (mygeomType === 'MultiPolygon'){
 //get the interior points for every polygon of the multipolygon
  retGeom = feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoints();
  }
  if (mygeomType === 'Polygon'){
 //just get the interiot point of the simple polygon
  retGeom = feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoint();
  }
  styles.push(new ol.style.Style({
      geometry: retGeom,
      image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: 'http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/data/icon.png',
        anchor: [0.75, 0.5],
        rotateWithView: true
      })
    }));
 return styles;  
}});
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/fatk7t4g/) to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems you are trying to give a picture to a Point feature in openlayers 3, not the polygon. OL3 defines several features like line, point, polygon. You can refer to the example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/custom-interactions.html