# In openlayers, how to fit (stretch) a picture from a url in the polygon?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to add a picture in a polygon
I found this answer [In openlayers 3, how to fill the polygon with a picture from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835929/in-openlayers-3-how-to-fill-the-polygon-with-a-picture-from-a-url)

However, I would like to fit (stretch) picture in the polygon (cause I aim to add feature that can resize the polygon later)
I've try

```
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'no-repeat');
```

but it didn't work.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLayers 3 and 4 you can create a pattern to fit the size the feature will occupy (similar to the gradient fitting the width in https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/canvas-gradient-pattern.html).  This changes with resolution and needs a style function, which must be synchronous, so the image should be preloaded.  In later versions it would be more complex as you would have to determine the 512 pixel origin OpenLayers will use instead of the feature's extent and pad or crop the pattern accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Styling feature with CanvasGradient or CanvasPattern</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      #map {
        background: #ccc;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>

      var flagStyle = function(feature, resolution) {
        var pattern;
        var img = feature.get('flag');
        if (img) {
          var cnv1 = document.createElement('canvas');
          var ctx1 = cnv1.getContext('2d');

          // Patterns are in canvas pixel space, so we adjust for the
          // renderer's pixel ratio
          var pixelRatio = ol.has.DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO;

          var extent = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
          var width = ol.extent.getWidth(extent) / resolution * pixelRatio;
          var height = ol.extent.getHeight(extent) / resolution * pixelRatio;
          if (width >= 1 && height >= 1) {
            cnv1.width = width;
            cnv1.height = height;
            ctx1.drawImage(img, 2, 12, 60, 40, 0, 0, width, height);

            var cnv2 = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx2 = cnv2.getContext('2d');
            pattern = ctx2.createPattern(cnv1, 'no-repeat');
          }
        }
        return new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: pattern
          })
        });
      };

      // Create a vector layer that makes use of the style function above…
      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: 'https://openlayersbook.github.io/openlayers_book_samples/assets/data/countries.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        }),
        style: flagStyle
      });

      vectorLayer.getSource().on('addfeature', function(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          feature.set('flag', img);
        }
        img.src = 'https://www.countryflags.io/' +
          feature.get('iso_a2').toLowerCase() + '/flat/64.png';
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          vectorLayer
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([7, 52]),
          zoom: 3
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time. It seems like image inside the canvas also zoom when we zoom the map (although it'll be fit when it finish render, maybe we need _updateWhileInteracting_ option). Beside, I found another solution, but it needs to use _ol-ext_ https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html

Comment: That issue can also be seen in the canvas gradient example, the gradient patterns don't adjust to the new zoom until the zoom has completed.  The ol-ext method is similar to OpenLayers Image Static, e.g. https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/reprojection-image.html

Comment: _"That issue can also be seen in the canvas gradient example"_  yes, I could see that and I think your answer handle it better.
_"The ol-ext method is similar to OpenLayers Image Static"_ yes, I realize that, I tried Image Static too. However, I pick ol-ext method cause it supports move, resize, scale image which things my new features need to.

Comment: Sorry, I tested and _updateWhileInteracting_ is not correct, should use **updateWhileAnimating** instead for adjust to the new zoom while zooming `var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ ..., updateWhileAnimating: true });`